# Falsify audio input from a microphone for another program in Java?

Tags: java, audio, input, microphone, mixing

I have not looked into the Java Sound API too much before I had this idea,
so I went and looked at the Tutorial by Oracle concerning this topic.
I did not find what I was looking for, though...

Basically, I need to take the audio feed from the microphone input
and mix in another audio file. This would be for Skype, to play background music.
Now the important thing about this is that the modified audio feed
would have to be used BY Skype instead of the original microphone-only audio.

Is there any (easy?) way to achieve this?

Regards,
Tom S.

Comment: Maybe you could divert the microphone data into a file. And then log the audio files into Skype, realtime: http://www.eham.net/ehamforum/smf/index.php?topic=76949.0

Comment: Another idea would be to create a virtual microphone driver that would get data from the Java program. Then you could get Skype to read from your virtual microphone. This is hardly "easy", though.

Comment: I've done things like this using Pulse-audio on Linux. You might be interested. I could repost a more detailed version of my earlier answer, but only if you're interested :)